# What is the difference between ce and ça?

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs, pronoms-impersonnels

*Ce* and *ça* both mean the same thing (this) in French, so what is the difference between them? When would someone use one over the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This answer will be about the pronouns, but note that *ce* (with variants *cet*, *cette*) is also a demonstrative adjective and as such will be followed by a noun and that *ça* should not be confused with *çà* which is an old synonym of *ici*.

*Ça* is an alternative form of *cela*; they can replace each other in most if not all contexts, but *ça* tend to be used more often (but not exclusively) when speaking, while *cela* tend to be used more often (but not exclusively) in writing.  One case where *cela* is used more often both orally and in writing is when it is opposed with *ceci*.

*Ce*, *ceci*, *cela* and *ça* are the neutral demonstrative pronouns. They don't replace a noun (forms with *celui*, *celle*, *ceux*, *celles* are used in those cases) but something implied or (part of) a sentence.

When they are opposed, *ceci* is used for the nearer (in space, in time or in the discourse), *cela* (or sometimes *ça*) for the further.  Alone, *ceci* is for something quite near and *cela* or *ça* for something quite far, but *cela* is also used for things near, especially for part of sentences which precedes the pronoun.

Usages of *ce* are more limited:

- in *ce que*, *ce qui*, *ce dont*, ... then it stands for a thing (it used to be able to stand for a person, but that's rare nowadays) or a (part of) a sentence.
- as subject of *être*, *ce* stands for what comes before (in that case it can be redundant and only used for emphasis), or the situation.
- it  is also sometimes used as the subject of *pouvoir* or *devoir*, when used as modal verbs (aka semi-auxiliaries).
- there are some other usages, more or less literary (*ce me semble*), more or less fixed remnants of older structures (*Ce disant, ...*)

and it is sometimes replaced with *ça* for emphasis.

Comment: Why is ce sometimes used as a pronoun? For example, c'est is a contraction of ce est, and means 'it is' or 'this is.'

Comment: @Orcris: I'm not sure it's exactly a pronoun in those uses -- or if it is, it's a strange one. Note that you write "ce sont" when what follows is plural; and note that the choice between "c'est" and "il est" depends chiefly on what follows ("c'est un homme" vs. "il est grand"; "c'est difficile à dire" vs. "il est difficile de dire ça").

Comment: This isn't correct....@UnFrancophone "c'est" is obviously a contraction of *ce* + *est* meaning *this is* or *it is*, where *ce* is *it* or *this*. It is most definitely a pronoun.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ce#French

Comment: This link has the real answer to the question: http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/indefinite-demonstrative-pronoun.htm

Comment: Sorry for use of *obviously*, didn't mean to be snippy.

Comment: Ca est une fois la bonne réponse. (Belgisisme)

Answer (score 0):

« il / elle est » becomes « c’est » and « ils / elles sont » becomes « ce sont » IF - 
an article is followed by a modified noun.

Example:

- he is a boy = c’est un garçon.
- they are boys. Ce sont les garçons. :)

« Ça » is an informal use of this and that as I know of. :)

Comment: they are => ils sont
these are boys => ce sont DES garçons