# Différence entre « ce », « il », « ça », « ceci » et « cela »

Tags: choix-de-mot, pronoms, démonstratifs, pronoms-impersonnels

Je connais une liste de mots qui ont des traductions très similaires :

> ce, il, ça, ceci, cela

Bien sûr, ces mots ne sont pas interchangeable dans certaines expressions idiomatiques (e.g. « c'est » ou « il y a » ), mais quand ils désignent une chose abstraite ou inanimée, peut-on tous les utiliser sans différence ? Je crois que ce n'est pas le cas.

Quelle différence y a-t-il entre « ce », « il », « ça », « ceci » et « cela » ?

Comment: (j'écris ma réponse en commentaire car je n'ai pas de source)

ça est cela sont identiques.

ceci est la version "plus proche" de cela.

"il" s'utilise quand on a déjà parlé du sujet. example: "Marc vient d'arriver, et il est très fatigué".

"ce" s'utilise normalement pour identifier un objet, et non pas le qualifier. example "c'est le frère de Marc", et non pas "il est le frère de Marc" (à ce que je sache.)

Je ne sais pas comment décrire exactement la difference entre "cela" et "il", mais un des usages de cela/ceci est quand on montre quelque chose au doigt.

Comment: Une partie de la réponse est ici:http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/what-is-the-difference-between-ce-and-%C3%A7a

Comment: En effet marc. "Cela" = "That"; "Ceci" = "This";

Comment: All the cases where you can use cela/ceci, you can translate to that/this, but it doesn't work the other way around, just sayin'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ce

« Ce » est un pronom impersonnel, c'est pronom simple indéfini démonstratif. Il est utilisé surtout avec verbe « être » dans l'expression « c'est » ou dans d'autres expressions impersonnelles.

> C'est une bonne idée ! 
>   C'est difficile à faire. 
>   C'est triste de perdre un ami. 
>   Étudier, c'est important.

En outre, on utilise « devoir + être » ou « pouvoir + être » après ce pronom.

> Ce doit être un bon restaurant. 
>   Ce peut être difficile.

Note: « Ce » est aussi un adjectif démonstratif.

### Ceci et cela

« Ceci » et « cela » sont utilisés comme des sujets de tous les autres verbes. Intéressant, « Ceci » est la contraction de « ce » + « ici » et « cela » est la contraction de « ce » + « là ». On utilise « ceci » pour parler d'objets à proximité et « cela » d'objets éloignés.

> Ceci va être facile. 
>   Cela me fait plaisir.

Ces pronoms peuvent aussi être objets directs et indirects.

> Donnez-lui cela de ma part. 
>   Qui a fait cela ?

### Ça

« Ça » est familier pour « ceci » et « cela ».

> Donne-lui ça de ma part. 
>   Qui a fait ça ? 
>   Ça me fait plaisir. 
>   Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça ? 
>   Je ne veux pas ceci (ou ça), je veux ça.

### Il et elle

« Il » et « elle » sont des pronoms. On doit choisir l'un d'eux selon le genre du nom (masculin ou féminin).

> Je vais au musée, il est ouvert jusqu'à 20h00. 
>   Où est la voiture ? Elle est chez Jean.

« Il » est aussi un pronom impersonnel (absence de sujet réel) utilisé dans de nombreux cas particuliers :

> Il faut lire. 
>   Il y a beaucoup de choses. 
>   Il se peut que … 
>   Il pleut.

---

Cette réponse est basée sur ces articles: [« French Indefinite Demonstrative Pronouns »](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/indefinite-demonstrative-pronoun.htm) et [« French Subject Pronouns »](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/ss/subjectpronouns_4.htm).