# When to use the dummy subject « il », as opposed to « cela/ça »

Tags: pronoms

I wrote in an email:

> **Il** lui coûterait sans doute **de l’avouer**, mais sa maîtrise de la cuisine japonaise est assez médiore...

I haven’t given it much thought until now, but when « il/cela/ça » serves as the dummy subject referring to the part after « de », I’m not completely sure when to use « il », as opposed to « cela/ça ».

The difference between « cela » and « ça » is about *formal vs informal*, but how do these two compare with « il »?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this matter, @Marc wrote a pretty accurate and complete answer, that you can find [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-ce-il-%C3%A7a-ceci-et-cela).

To add a little something to his answer, I'd say that both can be used in that case. ***Ça*** would be the everyday language version (considering the fact that "Ça" is a shortened version of "Cela", "Ceci") when ***Il*** would be a more elegant and impersonal one (regarding that particular case).

Comment: Hi. I noticed the post myself, but it seems that the dummy subject use of "il" doesn't get a mention there.

Comment: Oh well. He's kind of addressing it at the end. "« Il » est aussi un pronom impersonnel (absence de sujet réel) utilisé dans de nombreux cas particuliers", at least it looks like it to me.