# How can I choose between "ça" & "c’est" to write a sentence?

Tags: démonstratifs

When do I use in a sentence "ça" or "c’est". I know that each word has a meaning but I don't know which one to use when it comes to completing a sentence or phrase in an exam for example.

Comment: “C'est” contains a verb while “ça” doesn't. I suppose your question is rather to choose between “ce” and “ça”. You'll find answers about this here: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/what-is-the-difference-between-ce-and-%c3%a7a, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-ce-il-%c3%a7a-ceci-et-cela. If your problem is different, please make your question clearer by providing examples.

Answer (score 3):

***Ça*** is “this”, “that” or “it”, ***c’est*** could in most cases if not all, be translated as “this is”, “that is” or “it is”:

- Ça s’est bien passé → That went well
- Ça fonctionne → It works
- Ça me fait mal → It hurts me
- Ça fait du bien → This feels good
- C’est terminé → It’s over
- C’est ennuyant → It’s boring
- C’est de cette manière → That’s the way
- C’est mon ami Pierrot → This is my friend Pierrot

And in combination :

- C’est ça ! → That’s it!
- C’est ça qui est ça → “This is it”, or in other contexts, “It is what it is”
- Ça ? C’est mon chat. → That? That’s my cat.
- Ça, c’est mon chat → This is my cat (*ça* is not necessary in this case)

Comment: +1 car... c'est bien ça que c'est! ;-)

Comment: Basically, all this says is that “it/this/that is” is rendered as *c'est*, while “it/this/that” + another verb can be rendered as “ça” + verb.

Answer (score 1):

**A** The cedilla under c (ç) is used only when c is before a or u or o and when at the same time the sound of c is not that of k (ça, perçu, Açores), that is when the sound has to be that of double s, as in « passer », « poisson » et « percussion ». There is always an apostrophe in « c'est », which stand always for « ce est », a form never found in print ; the practice of contracting the two words into a single one when speaking is represented in writing by the apostrophe and this method of writing is called « elision » (same word form in French) ; you find again the word « ce » in the third person plural (ce sont) and in the négative form : « ce n'est pas » ; but then elision reappears for « ne » (same reason).

The following shouldn't be construed as a comprehensive perusal of the subject but merely as some of the facts that appear to be essential.

**B** The use of the two forms or more specifically of the two demonstrative pronouns is very similar insofar as the verb is « être » and there is an antecedent that has been clearly recognized ; often , when you can use « ça » you can also use « ce » and vice versa. « Ça » is a colloquial abbreviation of « cela » ; ideally then, every time « ça » is used « cela » can be used in its place, however, it is not quite so ; in certain cases it is not possible to do so because of the register in the remnant of the sentence; for instance in « Ça ira pas loin. » in which is found already a degree of informality because of the ellipse of « ne », changing « Ça » en « Cela » produces a rather odd sentence (Cela ira pas loin.); if the sentence is « Ça n'ira pas loin. » then the change becomes possible (Cela n'ira pas loin.).

> 1. Il n'y a pas assez de détail dans votre explication, mais ça/ce n'est pas la raison du manque de clarté.
> 2. -- Qu'est-ce que vous diriez d'aller ramer sur le lac?
>      -- Ce/Ça n'est pas l'idée que me fais d'une agréable après-midi, aujourd'hui. (*plutôt « ce » et moins formel : « C'est pas l'idée …»* )
> 3. -- Je lui ai expliqué qu'il n'y arriverait pas et pourquoi personne n'y arrive.
>      -- Ça l'a convaincu je paris…
>      -- Non, mais ça a été suffisant pour semer un doute dans son esprit.

The ready made phrase « Ça y est. » can be translated by a variety of English sentences, for instance « That's it. », « We've got it. » and « Here you are. ». Beware that « That's it. » is also the translation of « C'est ça. », which is not the same thing as « Ça y est. » ; the latter indicates that something that was expected finally happened, the former that a thing has been identified properly, that it is true. In that phrase, « Ça » cannot be replaced by « Ce ». In  « C'est ça. » « C » can't either be replaced by « Ça ».

> -- Il y a toujours un petit trou noir dans la pomme lorsqu'il y a un vers à l'intérieur.
>   -- C'est ça. (*or* « Cela est vrai. » *or* « C'est vrai. »)

In the last dialogue one could say « Ça est vrai. » and more naturally « Ça c'est vrai. »  rather if something else said before had not been true or if the locutor wanted to insist on the truth of what has been asserted. The equivalent « cela » does not express this insistance quite as pungently.

> 1. -- Un de mes camarades m'a dit pouvoir attraper une anguille à main nue lorsqu'elle est hors de l'eau.
>      -- C'est faux.
>      -- Un autre m'a dit que pour l'attraper ainsi il suffit de placer du papier journal entre la main et l'anguille.
>      -- Ça c'est vrai.
> 2. -- Il n'y a pas toujours un arc en ciel après la pluie.
>      -- Ça c'est vrai.

**C** When there is not an antecedent clearly defined as explained above things are different : only « ce » can be used; as stipulated in the TLFi, « « Ce » is [then] the subject of a proposition with the fonction of attributing an identification ».

> C'est moi, toi, lui, elle; ce sont eux, elles; fam. c'est eux, elles.
>
> C'est elle qui me l'a dit. 
>   C'est la course la plus longue de la journée.
>   Ce sont les fleurs qui poussent le plus haut en altitude, ou tout au moins des fleurs de l'une de ces sortes-là.